# Python Slice Notation with Comma/List

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice

I have come across some python code with slice notation that I am having trouble figuring out.
It looks like slice notation but uses a comma and a list:

```
list[:, [1, 2, 3]]
```

Is this syntax valid? If so what does it do?

**edit** looks like it is a 2D numpy array

Comment: Are you certain `list` is a list? It could be an instance of a class that overrides `__getitem__` in an unusual way.

Comment: Have you tried type(list)? Could be a numpy array or pandas dataframe.

Comment: @mattexx, I dont have the whole code, what does this do in numpy and pandas?

Comment: Numpy arrays and pandas dataframes use 2-d arrays, much like matlab and r. The first argument typically represents a slice of rows, while the second represents a slice of columns. So list[:,:3] would be all rows, first three columns. I'm not sure if either supports the exact notation you have in your question.

Comment: @mattexx: just so the OP isn't confused, it might be useful to emphasize that numpy arrays aren't fundamentally 2-D objects in the same way that some other datastructures are.  They're n-D.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that the object is really a `numpy` array, this is known as [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), and picks out the specified columns:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> a[:, [1,2,3]]
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> a[:, [1,3]]
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 5,  7],
       [ 9, 11]])
```

Note that this won't work with the standard Python list:

```
>>> a.tolist()
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
>>> a.tolist()[:,[1,2,3]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-17-7d77de02047a>", line 1, in <module>
    a.tolist()[:,[1,2,3]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Answer (score 4):

It generates a complex value and passes it to [`__*item__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def __getitem__(self, val):
...     print val
... 
>>> Foo()[:, [1, 2, 3]]
(slice(None, None, None), [1, 2, 3])
```

What it actually *performs* depends on the type being indexed.